# ConcurrentHashMap with complicated objects

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I've taken some concurrent LRU cache implementation from the web, they have there HashMap and synchronized blocks. What I want is to use ConcurrentHashMap and avoid (where posible) using synchronized blocks. I've put ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap and everything went wrong. Thread exits on map.get(key). Maybe my parameters of ConcurrentHashMap need to be customized somehow?

```
        private ConcurrentHashMap<Object, LRUListEntry> map;

        protected class LRUListEntry extends Object
        {
            LRUListEntry next;
            LRUListEntry prev;
            Object value;
            Object key;
            int hits;
            final int penalty = -1;

            public String toString()
            {
                return key + "=" + value;
            }

            public Object getKey()
            {
                return key;
            }

            public Object getValue()
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What went wrong?

Comment: you did not provide the relevant code. it is not the definition of the value class, it is the usage of the map

Comment: Was the original implementation, without the use of ConcurrentHashMap, tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `prev` and `next` LRU references are modified on every access to reorder the entry as the least recently used. The implementation assumes that these operations are being performed atomically, which is not true if the synchronized blocks are removed. Java's `LinkedHashMap` is a nice implementation of your snippet, and is provided in the standard library.

[ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/) provides a concurrent version of the LRU algorithm. The [design document](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/Design) describes at a high-level the ideas used. This project was a basis for [Guava's Cache](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), with the modified approach described in this [presentation](http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/files/ConcurrentCachingAtGoogle.pdf). Both projects have good code level documentation and unit tests if you are interested in the low-level details.